# SQL sargable and performance tuning

Tags: sql, datepart, sql-tuning

I am using the following where predicate to get only Monday to Fridays tickets from one of our DW tables.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT TicketID 
FROM Tickets AS T
WHERE DATEPART(DW,T.StartDate) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 ....`
```

Would it be possible to let me know if the `DATEPART` predicate is sargable please?

I took a look at the actual execution plan and it uses an index seek even with the `DATEPART` function.

We have already optimised many of our old queries by modifying the where predicates, analysing the plan, set statistics io on,  etc. For this one I am not sure if there is a better way to get tickets only from mon - fri (shifts..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your query is likely index selectivity because of your BETWEEN clause.  If you're selecting 5 out of 7 week days, the optimizer is going to perform a table scan.

Comment: We already used an index seek before instead of a table scan. We changed the design anyway now to a date dimension join instead of the where predicate.